# How do I get first word from a line in txt file to be col1 data on previous line

Tags: php, awk, cygwin

I need the date (dd.mm.yy) found in column 1 (like awk $1?) or as the first word (format is always dd.mm.yy) on a line in txt file to be used as col 1 on the previous line,and all next lines until a new date is found on a line in col 1, and then the new date should be put in col 1 on the previous line and all next lines until a new date is found in col 1 on a line.

Windows 10 Pro, Cygwin, PHP 7.x

I now file (PHP) the file, then foreach line preg_split (PHP) the current line to get an array of words and positions using PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE to get the data and position of a word as array.

The first element in the preg_split array for a line is always [0]="" (empty) and position [1]=0. If the next element matches a "preg_match('/[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}/', $element)" and its position is at least X but not more than Y it is the date that I want, to be used as the first element for ex in an array of the elements on the previous line, but previous line only upwards, the line the date is found on, and all subsequent lines until a new date is found on a line, and then that new date should be used as date on the previous line the new date is found on instead of the previous date...

I know awk can read lines before and after a match, but how do I get to set the date as first element in the array (or whatever) on the line before the line the date is found on?

Input:

XXXXXX
  18.05.19
                   YYYYYYYYYYY
                   TTTTTTT
                   UUUUUUUUU
  17.05.19
                   KKKKKKKKK
                   GGGGGG

Expected output:
18.05.19 XXXXXXX
18.05.19 YYYYYYYYYYY
18.05.19 TTTTTTT
17.05.19 UUUUUUUUUUUU
17.05.19 KKKKKKKKKK
17.05.19 GGGGGGG

I have no problems attaching a date to subsequent lines after the the date, but the problem is how to attach the date to the previous line instead of a possibly existing date.

EDIT:

I forgot to say that I am on Windows + Cygwin.

The source file to read from has multiple leading spaces on every line, don't know if this matters. I removed these manually for testing, but it did not help (below is the cleaned original file). And the initial sample of the to-read-file was somewhat minimised, the real file has multiple words on the lines, and I need them all (I suppose this can be done by using $0).

This is what I tried

```
    #!/bin/bash
    awk '/^([0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{2}/ { date=$1; next }
    NR>1 { print date, prev }
    { prev=$1 }
    END { print date, prev }' Infile.txt
```

on Infile.txt

```
    TTTTT 15MIKROG/ML
    13.11.12            
    90X0.3ML
    D. xxx yyy     
    S. 1 drop 1/d     
    LKE KJJKJJKJK    
    TTTTT 15MIKROG/ML
    22.05.12            
    90X0.3ML
    D. cccc kkkk 
    S. 1 tip 1/d MMMMM LLLLL 
    GGGGG HHHHHH                
    05.10.11   MEDFG 2.5ML          
    D. xxx ooo                   
    S. 1 TIP 1/d MMMMM SSSS 
    GGGGGG HHHHHHH                
    CVCVCVC 20MG/ML+5MG/ML             
    03.03.11
    60X0.2ML
```

On rows containing a date that date should be applied, as said, to the previous row and subsequent rows until a new date is found.

But if a date has something (anything but white space) after it on the same row, here only row

```
    05.10.11   MEDFG 2.5ML
```

then the date should not be applied to the previous row, but only to that row and next rows (until a new date is found, and the it should check whether the date is the only thing on the row, and if so, apply the date to the previous row and subsequent row, etc.

So the result the commentators have presented is the expected result, the thing is that I cannot reproduce the result.

EDIT 2:

The PHP way I did this, using SplFileObject, preg_split:

```
    $splFileObjectFile=new SplFileObject($theFileToProcess);

    foreach($splFileObjectFile as $lineNr=>$lineContent)
        {
        $lineContentArr = preg_split('/ {2,}/', $lineContent, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        // To database
        foreach($lineContentArr as $wdKey=>$wordData)
            {
            $wordNr=$wdKey;
            $dataValue=$wordData[0];
            $posValue=$wordData[1];
            $lineNr=$lineNr;
            ...
```

Using SplFileObject I got the line number, and with preg_split at every 2 or more spaces I got the words on a row in an array of sub-arrays, in each of which the word itself and its position on the row.

All this inserted into a temp SQLite3 database with columns for line nr, word nr, word position and the word itself.

Then some SQL to get the first date, if the row the date was found on had nothing but the date, more SQL to update previous row date with this date, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '
    /^([0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{2}/ { date=$1; next }
    NR>1 { print date, prev }
    { prev=$1 }
    END { print date, prev }
' file
18.05.19 XXXXXX
18.05.19 YYYYYYYYYYY
18.05.19 TTTTTTT
17.05.19 UUUUUUUUU
17.05.19 KKKKKKKKK
17.05.19 GGGGGG
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. Very sorry for the delay, something came up. And I edited the question somewhat.

Comment: Feedback on my solution and in what way you've modified your question would be far more useful than `And I edited the question somewhat`. That sounds like you expect me to go read your updated question and try to figure out what changed and then run my script to try to figure out in what way it didn't behave as desired instead of you just telling me, etc. YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: I have no feedback on your solution, other than that I was not able to produce the same results you did given the same input. Obviously I did something wrong. Therefore I did it the hard way, using PHP, see edited question. This PHP way of doing this was not what I was looking for, but as I am on a schedule I had to do something. Thank You for Your efforts, though.

Comment: `I was not able to produce the same results` is about as useful as saying `it didn't work`. Not much we can do to help you figure out how to make it work given that - it's like telling your mechanic that your car "doesn't work" and hoping she can fix it from that. Glad you figured something out with PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ed beat me, but good exercise.

```
/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}$/ {date=$1; next}
{if(last!="") {print date, last} last=$1}
END {print date, last}
```

```sh
awk '
>   /^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}$/ {date=$1; next}
>   {if(last!="") {print date, last} last=$1}
>   END {print date, last}
> ' <<EOF
>                    XXXXXX
> 18.05.19
>                    YYYYYYYYYYY
>                    TTTTTTT
>                    UUUUUUUUU
> 17.05.19
>                    KKKKKKKKK
>                    GGGGGG
> EOF
18.05.19 XXXXXX
18.05.19 YYYYYYYYYYY
18.05.19 TTTTTTT
17.05.19 UUUUUUUUU
17.05.19 KKKKKKKKK
17.05.19 GGGGGG
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. Very sorry for the delay, something came up. And I edited the question somewhat.